# How to change Rallys Test Folder status

Tags: testing, rally

Is there a way to remove the current test status from a Rally Test Folder?

I create test plans from these folders which carry their own test status, I can manage those, but our team updated the folder status when we moved to rally initially. I would not like to export to csv, wondering if there's a UI tool built in to Rally to reset the status.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status is a rollup field, so it will always reflect the current status of the test cases contained within.  There's no way to "reset" in.